# Laravel boot method

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my models I've setup boot methods so when I softdelete a record the related records are softdeleted aswell. Like this:

Company.php

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($company) {
            $company->department()->delete();
        });
    }
```

Department.php:

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($department) {
            dd('test');
        });
    }
```

So when I want to softdelete a company the departments should also be softdeleted. But when I `dd` in `static::deleting`(Department.php) this is not reached. When I `dd` like this:

Department.php

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        dd('test');
        static::deleting(function($department) {
        });
    }
```

Result is `test`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have use SoftDeletes; in your models??

Comment: Yes I've specified that in all my models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your Company.php model:

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Department');
}
```

Add this to your Department.php model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

Update your boot method in Company.php to reference

```
$company->departments()->delete()
```

Then you should take out the boot method from the Department.php file as this is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

in Company Model:

1. Describe relation between company and department:

```php
public function departments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Department::class);
}
```

2. Iterate each department for deleting in method boot() within Company Model:

```php
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(
        function($company){
        $company->departments()->
            each(fn($department)=>$department->delete());
    });
}
```

In Department Model: describe relation between department and company

```php
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```